# Prove that $R$ is a total order

Tags: order-theory

Prove that $R$ is a total order

$$R=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}~|~ x\geq y\}$$

I just need to figure out the final portion for total order. I already have it at partial order.

Thanks for the help

Comment: A total order is *antisymmetric*.

Comment: Antisymmetry is not enough: divisibility is an antisymmetric relation on the positive integers, but it is not a total order. You need to show that any two elements of $\Bbb R^2$ are *comparable*.

Comment: @DavidWheeler Yeah, I agree. That comment was made before an edit.

Comment: @Seven Yes I made the edit to fix my mistake. How do I prove that any two elements of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ that $(x,y) \in R$ or $(y,x) \in R$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it at a partial order then the remaining condition you need to check is totality, i.e., for any $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ that $x \geq y$ or $y \geq x$.

Comment: Let $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.

How do I go from there? Are they scenarios?

Comment: How you proceed depends on what properties of $\mathbb{R}$ you are assuming (allowed to use).

Comment: Do I just use two cases? I am not sure what properties you're referring to.

Comment: @Alfredo For any real $x$ and any real $y$, can you assert that *either* $x\geq y$ *or* $y\geq x$ is true? $~$ Why? $~$ (What is the definition of $\geq$ that you've been given? What is a real number? ... What did you use to show partial order?)

Comment: 1) Reflexive: Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then, $x\geq x$. Thus, $(x,x) \in R$. 
  
  2) Anti-symmetric: Let $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,x) \in R$. Then, $x\geq y$ and $y\geq x$. The only time when this holds is when $x$ and $y$ are the same value. Therefore, $x=y$.
  
  3) Transitive: Let $(x,y) \in R$ and Let $(y,z) \in R$. Thus, $x\geq y$ and $y\geq z$. By fact 7, if $x\geq y$ and $y\geq z$, then $x\geq y\geq z$. Thus, $x\geq z$. Therefore, $(x,z) \in R$.

Comment: If you look at your proof for transitivity, you use a "fact 7". It is this list of facts that you have at your disposable that dictates how you can proceed. Different books and classes will assume a different set of facts (that are all equivalent) and so your proof will depend on which ones you are "allowed" to use.